# Given a bivector, determine the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into symplectic leaves

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, poisson-geometry

Say I have a bivector, given by $f(z) \partial_x \wedge \partial_y$, where $f(z)$ is a smooth function of $z$. How do I determine the decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into symplectic leaves from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the bivector field by $$\Pi=f(z)\partial_{x}\wedge\partial_{y}.$$
There is an associated vector bundle map $$\Pi^{\sharp}:T^{*}\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}^{3}:\alpha\mapsto\iota_{\alpha}\Pi,$$
which takes a one-form $\alpha$ and contracts $\Pi$ with it. The symplectic foliation integrates the (singular) distribution $\text{Im}(\Pi^{\sharp})$. In this case, we have
\begin{align}
\text{Im}(\Pi^{\sharp})&=\text{Span}\{\Pi^{\sharp}(dx),\Pi^{\sharp}(dy),\Pi^{\sharp}(dz)\}\\
&=\text{Span}\{f(z)\partial_{y},f(z)\partial_{x}\}.
\end{align}
Note that this gives at each point $(x,y,z)$ either a zero-dimensional or a two-dimensional subspace, depending on whether or not $z$ is a zero of $f$.
It follows that the symplectic leaves are the  following:

1) Each horizontal plane $z=c$ is a leaf whenever $f(c)\neq 0$.

2) If $f(c)=0$, then all points $(x,y,c)$ are symplectic leaves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What happens if instead I have a bivector field like $(x \partial_x + y\partial_y)\wedge \partial_z$? I see that this is similar to what you have above, but it is more like an addition of two bivector fields of the form above. How does this differ?

Comment: @Sorey As above, we now have \begin{align}\text{Im}(\Pi^{\sharp})&=\text{Span}\{\Pi^{\sharp}(dx),\Pi^{\sharp}(dy),\Pi^{\sharp}(dz)\}\\&=\text{Span}\{x\partial_{z},y\partial_{z},-x\partial_{x}-y\partial_{y}\}.\end{align} Every point $(0,0,z)$ is a leaf, because the distribution is zero at those points. In other points, the distribution is spanned by the vertical vector field $\partial_{z}$ and the vector field $-x\partial_{x}-y\partial_{y}$, which points to the $z$-axis in radial direction. So the other leaves are half-planes going outwards from the $z$-axis.

Comment: Ok, great. One last thing - I did one on my own, with the bi-vector field $(x\partial_y + y\partial_x)\wedge \partial_z$. We get that 

$$\text{Im}(\Pi^{\#}) = \text{Span}\{y\partial_z,x\partial_z,-y\partial_x-x\partial_y\}$$

 So, again all points $(0,0,z)$ are leaves, and the distribution is spanned by $\partial_z$ and $-x\partial_y - y\partial_x$. This still points to the $z$-axis in the radial direction, correct? So would the leaves be half-planes still?

Comment: @Sorey The vector field $x\partial_{y}+y\partial_{x}$ does not always point in the radial direction. If you draw it carefully, you will see that its integral curves are branches of hyperbolas. So the leaves in this case are the points on the $z$-axis, and sheets of hyperbolic cylinders.